# AngularJS populating an object in a factory that is accessible throughout the website

Tags: angularjs

I have a user factory that has an object called userProperties that I populate when a user logs in to the system. A function named login() is then called that calls a function named set() that "sets the user", or populates the userProperties object.

user.factory.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('user', user);

    /* @ngInject */
    function user($http, authToken, $q, $state) {

        var userProperties = {};

        return {
            login: login,
            logout: logout,
            set: set,
            isSet: isSet,
            get: get,
            isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
        };

        function login(email, password) {
            return $http.post('/api/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }).then(function (response) {
                authToken.setToken(response.data.jwt);
                set(response.data.user);
                return response;
            });
        }

        function logout() {
            authToken.setToken();
            $state.go('login');
        }

        function set(data) {
            userProperties = data;
        }

        function get() {
            return userProperties;
        }           

        function isSet() {
            return !isEmpty(userProperties) ? true : false;
        }

        function isLoggedIn() {
            return authToken.getToken() ? true : false;
        }

        function isEmpty(obj) {
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { return false; }
            }
            return true;
        }       

    }

}());
```

I am then able to use this code in controllers throughout the website. For example inside Header controller, Home controller, Profile controller etc.

But if I don't login manually, but refresh the site, then I have a problem because then I am not populating the userProperties object as I did when someone logged in. So I need to do a check when people click the refresh button.

Something similar to the code below. I tried to run this code in a run block before everything else in the app, but still did not appear in controllers because it is async.

```
if (user.isLoggedIn() && !user.isSet()) {
    $http.get('/api/user/0') // id: 0 is the id of the logged in user
        .then(function (response) {
            user.set(response.data);
        });
}
```

but the problem here is that even if I do this I can't use the user factory in controllers and access the userProperties object that got populated because it is async.

Profile.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Profile', Profile);

    /* @ngInject */
    function Profile($scope, user) {
        $scope.user = user.get();
        console.log($scope.user);
    }

}());
```

the code above for Profile controller outputs an empty object to the console.

My alternative is to do something like this in ui-router, resolve it before Profile controller and set the user here. But then I have to do this everywhere I need the user. In Home controller, in Header controller and so on.

```
.state('profile', {
    url: '/user/:id',
    templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile.tpl.html',
    resolve: {
        userResolve: function ($http, $q, user) {
            return $http.get('/api/user/0')
                .then(function (response) {
                    user.set(response.data);
                });
        }
    },
    controller: 'Profile'
});
```

What should I do in order to do this once and have it available throughout the website? Or do I need to resolve before every state?

Comment: Why don't you use cookies or local Storage?

Comment: Does not matter if I use cookies or local storage. it is still async.

Comment: If you use cookies or local Storage, then there is no need of call

Comment: that is true. I might do that, but is it possible to resolve in a run block? lets say I need to get some data from the database before the controllers init, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can not do that with $http. You should try to manually bootstrap the application. And before you bootstrap, just send the normal jQuery call to get the response. Though not a clean solution but can work for you

Comment: Don't store the user information in the service. Store a promise of the user information. And in every controller needing the user information, use user.get().then() to access the user information when it's available (or use a resolve so that your controller is instantiated only when the user promise is resolved).

Comment: JB Nizet could you please give an example of how I would do that? That would be very helpful If I learned it.